# How to get a TypeSafe URL to a static resource in Yesod

Tags: url, haskell, routes, yesod, type-safety

I was wondering if someone could tell me how I get a TypeSafe URL to a static resource. I've got "/static" as a subsite serving files, but I'm unclear on how to refer to specific files from there using typesafe URLs. The idea is that I could include them in things like addScript and such.

I am very new to Yesod, but I couldn't find an example like this in either the Yesod book or in the FPComplete tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this: `src=@{StaticR img_myimage_png}`

Yesod looks inside the static directory and the file name will contain the directory name separated by `_`. Replace `.` with `_` too.

Comment: How would I get that as a route i.e. something I could pass to addScript?

Comment: Okay, so this is assuming that I"m using scaffolding, which I probably will end up doing. Anybody know how to do it without scaffolding?

Comment: `addScript` should take `StaticR img_myimage_png` as a param. I have only used the scaffolded site so you probably want to check the Yesod Book for creating subsites manually.