# How to use image under static directory as background in Yesodweb?

Tags: haskell, yesod

New to Yesod and I wonder how to use an image under directory static/img as the background image of a div. I use the Scaffolding site and have tried:

```
.mydiv {
  background-image: url("static/img/bg.jpg");
}
```

But it seems the url at last changes to `http://myhost/tmp/static/img/bg.jpg`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a TypeSafe URL to a static resource in Yesod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929610/how-to-get-a-typesafe-url-to-a-static-resource-in-yesod)

Comment: Try putting this: `/static/img/bg.jpg` instead ?

Comment: @Sibi It works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you were using lucius template, the real css file was autogenerated in temporary location `/tmp` on runtime and used the relative path. What you need is [type-safe URL](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics#basics_resources_and_type_safe_urls) which verifies URL validity on compile time.

If you're using scaffold template, then you can represent it as `@{StaticR img_bg_jpg}` according to [this](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template#scaffolding-and-the-site-template_static_files)

Note: With old version of `yesod-static` and template, `stack clean` may be required to reflect changes in static directory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the compiler complains "Variable not in scope: img_bg_jpg :: Route Static". I have the routes defined in file "config/routes" and there is "mkYesodData "App" $(parseRoutesFile "config/routes")" in Foundation.hs to generate router. Am I miss something to let compiler know where to find img_bg_jpg?

Comment: @hliu `img_bg_jpg` should be defined automatically from Settings.StaticFiles by TemplateHaskell. Did you reload on ghci? `:r` wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: I use command "stack exec -- yesod devel" to run the server in develop mode.  After put the image into img directory, I re-run and the compiler shows error still. Use following path can get this problem. 1) stack new  test-static-img yesod-simple; 2) copy test.jpg into static/img/; 3) modify templates/default-layout.lucius, modify the third line to background-image:url(@{StaticR  img_test_jpg}); 4) stack exec -- yesod devel

Comment: I doubt the static file not handled automatically? Maybe some codes should be added to make the image file be handled by Yesod.

Comment: @hliu I have no problem with your commands. It should work. If you're reusing existing project, could you try `stack build`? It seems `yesod devel` can't detect static resource modification at all.

Comment: you are right. I run stack clean at first, then it works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I needed to run `stack build`. Thank you @jeiea and @hliu. Maybe this and the `stack clean` should be included the answer.

Comment: Had the same problem and resolved the compilation error only after running `stack clean`. I too suggest to mention this in the answer.

Comment: @frt @dimsuz It seems the latest `yesod-static` includes staticDevel, which reflects changes without `stack clean`. If not, let me know. For now I will append that as note.

Comment: I use `touch` instead of `stack clean`: `touch src/Settings/StaticFiles.hs`.  Cleaning everything with _stack clean_ leads to long-time rebuilds, touching _StaticFiles.hs_ leads to quick rebuild and in most cases is sufficient.  Though this works only until you're under __*nix__.